# How many positive integer solutions are there to the equation $(a + b + c + d) < N$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Here's my attempt:

My thinking is that this is the same as finding all the non-negative $a, b, c, d$ such that $a + b + c + d = M$ where $M \in \{0, 1, ..., N - 4\}$. Which further reduces to a stars and bars problem, thus we get:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-4} {{k+4-1} \choose {k}}$.

But this seems to be incorrect. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Hint: This is the same as finding solutions to $a+b+c+d+e = N$.

Comment: Where a,b,c,d,e are positive integers? I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: Maybe it's sum from zero to $N-5$, because $(a + b + c + d) < N$ is equivalent to $(a + b + c + d) \le N-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have $N$ doughnuts and want to distribute $\lt N$ of them among $4$ people, A, B, C, and D, with everyone getting at least $1$ doughnut. So I will keep the rest to eat myself. The number of ways to do this is the number of ways to distribute exactly $N$ doughnuts among $5$ people, A, B, C, D, and I, with everyone getting at least $1$.

So I line up the $N$ doughnuts, like this, with a little space between them.
$$ O\quad O \quad O \quad O\quad O \quad O \quad O\quad O \quad O \quad O\quad O \quad O \quad O\quad O $$
 There are $N-1$ interdoughnut gaps, and I choose $4$ of them to put separators into. A will get the doughnuts from the left end to the first separator, B will get the doughnuts from the first separator to the second, and so on. I will get the ones from the last separator to the right end.  Choosing where the separators go  can be done in $\binom{N-1}{4}$ ways.

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense.

Comment: You are welcome. I should try to find less thin doughnuts,

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> Obviously, the desired result vanishes out when $\ds{N \leq 4}$. So, we consider the case $\ds{N \geq 5}$.

The number of combination with $\ds{a + b + c + d = s}$ $\ds{\pars{~s \geq 4~}}$
is given by:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{a\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\sum_{b\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
\sum_{c\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\sum_{d\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\delta_{a + b + c + d,s}}
=\sum_{a\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\sum_{b\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
\sum_{c\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\sum_{d\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{-a - b - c - d + s + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}
{1 \over z^{s + 1}}\pars{\sum_{a\ =\ 1}^{\infty}z^{a}}^{4}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{s + 1}}\pars{z \over 1 - z}^{4}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}
{1 \over z^{s - 3}\pars{1 - z}^{4}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}
{1 \over z^{s - 3 - k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\delta_{s - 3 - k,1}
={-4 \choose s - 4}\pars{-1}^{s}={s - 1 \choose s - 4}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\pars{s - 1}\pars{s - 2}\pars{s - 3} \over 6}}
\end{align}

> The number of combination with $\ds{a + b + c + d < N}$ $\ds{\pars{~N \geq 5~}}$
>   is given by:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{s\ =\ 4}^{N - 1}{\pars{s - 1}\pars{s - 2}\pars{s - 3} \over 6}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{N^{4} - 10N^{3} + 35N^{2} - 50N + 24 \over 24}}
\end{align}
with $\ds{N \geq 5}$ and zero otherwise $\ds{\pars{~N < 5~}}$.

> A few values are given by:

[image]